# Can't login in minIO with docker compose

Tags: docker-compose, minio

I am trying to use minIO with docker docker compose and Laravel, so I have the following docker-compose

### MINIO

```
minio:
    image: minio/minio
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
      - "9001:9001"
    environment:
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: minio
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: 12345678
    volumes:
      - ~/docker/minio-data:/data
    command: server --console-address :9001 /data
```

### NGINX

```
nginx:
    hostname: nginx
    image: nginx:1.17
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
    volumes:
      - ./folder:/var/www/html/app
      - ./folder/docker/virtualhost.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

so, I start the containers

```
minio      | API: http://172.19.0.2:9000  http://127.0.0.1:9000 
minio      | 
minio      | Console: http://172.19.0.2:9001 http://127.0.0.1:9001 
minio      | 
minio      | Documentation: https://docs.min.io
```

then I access to minio console to login and when I tried to login I get this error:

> The authorization header is malformed; the region is wrong; expecting
> 'us-east-1'.

Answer (score 0):

I tried out this example, and logging in to MinIO at http://localhost:9001 works fine. This likely has something to do with your nginx configuration - and we cannot figure out what without the actual nginx configuration. You might want to check this doc: https://docs.min.io/docs/setup-nginx-proxy-with-minio

Please know you can find us at https://slack.min.io/ 24/7/365. If you have commercial questions, please reach out to us on hello@min.io or on our Ask an Expert Chat functionality at https://min.io/pricing?action=talk-to-us.